# Book series about a group of teens with powers (telepathy, shape-shifting into a dragon, weapon creation, etc)

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel, magic

I read this book when I was around 13 or 14. It was between 2015 and 2016. I remember it was the last book in the series and the back cover had an illustration of an (old) man wearing a green bowler hat and suit.

Basically, this group of teens, possibly three boys and two girls, were tasked to take down an evil sorceress. This sorceress had a daughter called Eris and she killed all her boyfriends. One of the female characters could turn into a Chinese dragon and was related to a villain from one of the first books.

I remember something about a golem taking the place of the main male protagonist and I also remember that the final battle took place on the Golden Gate Bridge in San Francisco. Additionally, the teens posted a spell on YouTube to try to find the remaining kids to fulfil the prophecy.

There were lots of elements involving time travel, knights (briefly), and hamburgers.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  We don't know how old you are, so approximately what year was it when you read this?

Comment: It was between 2015 and 2016

Comment: Reminds me a bit of the 3rd X-Men movie:  Teens with super powers, check.  Shapeshifter, telepath, check, check.  Climax on Golden Gate Bridge, check.  Old man in a suit, check.  (Xavier doesn't wear a green hat though)  Girl who kills all her boyfriends, almost check, as anyone who touches Rogue could die from it.  Evil sorceress - sort of check, that is where Phoenix starts going dark.  Time travel - check in the later movies, but not that one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a guess since I don't own a copy of the books, but could this be [The Magnificent 12 Series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/49355-the-magnificent-12) by Michael Grant?

In the first book, [The Call](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7719324-the-call), we are told twelve children have to gather together to battle the wicked *Pale Queen* and her daughter *Ereskigal*. The daughter's name *Eriskigal* is close to *Eris*, though apparently in the book she is known as *Risky*.

A review of the last book in the series, [The Power](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17331397-the-power), mentions the golem and the final battle on the Golden Gate bridge.

> Meanwhile, back in Sedona, the golem pretending to be Mack, is being fought over by new-chief-bully Angie and Risky, the Pale Queen's evil (but drop-dead gorgeous daughter). Which all leads to a stunning climax on the Golden Gate Bridge.